# How does LXC setup its root mount point?

Tags: mount, lxc, namespace

I am trying to experiment with mount namespace in Ubuntu. So far I can create an empty mount namespace using the following:

```
# mkdir test
# unshare --mount
# mount none test -t tmpfs
# cd test
# pivot_root . . 
# cd / <--- test becomes /
```

When I check a `LXC` Ubuntu container, the `mount` command displays the following:

[image]

Since the mount namespace initially gets a copy of the mount points, I presume the `/dev/sda1` inside the container is the global `/dev/sda1` (because there is no `/dev/sda1` inside the container once it is started), and yet the contents of the `/` inside the container correspond to its rootfs. Can someone familiar with LXC please explain what mount operations does LXC do before it does its `pivot_root` inside the container ?

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of the text into the question. They are not-copyable, so no one can easily quote parts of your question. Instead, copy the text and place it into the code block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what LXC actually does, let's create a new container and trace its startup process via `strace(1)`:

```
[root@localhost /]# lxc-create -n testcontainer -t debian
[root@localhost /]# strace -e trace=clone,chdir,mount,pivot_root,execve \
                           -f -o lxclog \
                           lxc-start -n testcontainer
```

The resulting trace is written to **lxclog** file, and here are the most relevant parts of it (ellipses are added by me where some non-significant calls are omitted):

```
14671 clone(child_stack=0x7fff9379eb80, flags=CLONE_NEWNS|CLONE_NEWUTS|CLONE_NEWIPC|CLONE_NEWPID|CLONE_NEWNET|SIGCHLD) = 14677
<...>
14677 mount("/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/rootfs", "/usr/lib64/lxc/rootfs", 0x7fe4c2d10eac, MS_BIND|MS_REC, NULL) = 0
<...>
14677 chdir("/usr/lib64/lxc/rootfs")    = 0
14677 pivot_root(".", "/usr/lib64/lxc/rootfs/lxc_putold") = 0
14677 chdir("/")
<...>
14677 execve("/sbin/init", ["/sbin/init"], [/* 1 var */]) = 0
```

First, a new process (PID 14677) is spawned by `lxc-start` (PID 14671) using `clone(2)` and is placed in new mount namespace (`CLONE_NEWNS` flag). Then inside this new mount namespace the root file system of the container (**/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/rootfs**) is bind-mounted (`MS_BIND` flag) to **/usr/lib64/lxc/rootfs**, which then becomes the new root. Finally, when the container initialization is finished, the process 14677 becomes the container's `init`.

The important thing here is that the root directory of container's mount namespace is the bind mount of the directory *belonging to the host's root FS*. This is why the root mount of the container still has **/dev/sda1** as a source in the `mount(8)` output. However, there also is a difference which is not shown by `mount(8)` - to see it, try `findmnt(8)` inside the container:

```
root@testcontainer:~# findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE                     FSTYPE    OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/sda1[/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/rootfs]
```

Compare this to the output of `findmnt(8)` from the host system:

```
[root@localhost /]# findmnt
TARGET                                SOURCE                    FSTYPE     OPTIONS
/                                     /dev/sda1
```

Note that the *source* is the same, but inside the container you also see the source directory of the bind mount.

Comment: One question regarding `bind` mount used in LXC: Any changes made inside the container to its root directory will be reflected in the `rootfs` folder in the global `/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/` directory. Is this done for reasons for saving the state of the container, so if it is shutdown and restarted, it can resume from the last change to its root directory ? Thanks.

Comment: I asked a follow up: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/513734/63934