# Restrictions on pivot_root to switch root filesystem

Tags: mount, lxc, namespace

This question is a follow up to the question I asked on [how LXC setups up its root mount point](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/513036/63934).

For a container named `testcontainer`, LXC uses bind mount to mount `/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/rootfs` to `/usr/lib64/lxc/rootfs` and then later switches to that directory and uses `pivot_root` as `pivot_root(.,.)` ([source](https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/master/src/lxc/conf.c#L1516)).

My confusion is that why does LXC use a bind mount, and its related restriction on `pivot_root`. My question is that if LXC already knows the `rootfs` it needs to use (`/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/rootfs`), then why doesn't it just `chdir` to that directory and do a `pivot_root` there ? If I try to do test this, `pivot_root` doesn't allow it complaining:

`pivot_root: failed to change root from . to . : Device or resource busy`.

If I understand it correctly, bind mount replicates the directory at a different point, then why can't we just `pivot_root` when in the directory `/var/lib/lxc/testcontainer/rootfs` and why do we have to bind mount it somewhere else and apply `pivot_root` there ?

Comment: I don't feel that I'm ready to write a complete answer to this follow-up, but I already tried to dig into this question before (while dealing with Docker internals), so I can point out to the following: `pivot_root` has the requirement `new_root and put_old must not be on the same filesystem as the current root`, but de facto the kernel checks not _filesystems_ (for equality), but _mounts_ (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/085b7755808aa11f78ab9377257e1dad2e6fa4bb/fs/namespace.c#L3263).

Comment: The consequence here is that you can `pivot_root` to the dir from the same FS by bind-mounting it to somewhere and then `pivot_root`ing to this mount. This is what the kernel recommends (https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/085b7755808aa11f78ab9377257e1dad2e6fa4bb/fs/namespace.c#L3213), and this is what LXC does (actually, this kernel comment is quoted in LXC source you link to - https://github.com/lxc/lxc/blob/60c20c6e0e85efb236e00eb3396f064e9e7c82e8/src/lxc/conf.c#L1487).

Comment: The reason why I don't consider this as a full answer is that I can not clearly elaborate and explain why `pivot_root`ing is forbidden to the same file system, but is permitted to the _bind mount_ of the directory from the same file system. Unfortunately, I could not find any detailed explanation in mailing lists or git log.

Comment: @DanilaKiver Thank you for your help. If you find a complete answer, then let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Just to double check, `pivot_root` used with two arguments as `pivot_root(. , .)` is merely to prevent the old root to me mounted anywhere inside the mount namespace ?

Comment: The idea behind `pivot_root` is that after changing the root to new one (_the first argument_) you may completely unmount the old root (in case of containers - for isolation). To be able to do this, you need to move the old root to somewhere beneath the new root (_the second argument_), else you will fail with an error like "target is busy". That is what `pivot_root` does. As to "why both arguments are the same" - for me this seems to be some trickery (in old LXC versions the second argument was _under_ the new root). Not sure what was the reason for this change.